# Impersonation file upload impact

Tags: asp.net

i have a admin system, currently allow login user to upload a file,
but i found that it can not overwrite the file with same file name, it return access denied error

im wondering if i set impersonation = true in web.config, what impact will have?
(i know there is another way to solve my upload overwrite issue, but just want to ask the impact of impersonation)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is obviously a permission related issue so you need to check for permissions on folder for the users application pool, network service and aspnet

Check read only attribute of the files that are throwing access denied. many times, user uploads images from CD.

When you are saving file, try to remove read only flag and save the file so that when overwritten not throw errors.